# Is there a way to see the date that a github repository switched from public to private or vice versa

Tags: github

I was hoping there was a log somewhere but I don't see one.
The point is to understand what exactly was in the repository when it was public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a "[public event](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/github-event-types#publicevent)" (When a private repository is made public)

But you do not have the opposite (When a public repository is made private).
Which means you will not see it through the [GitHub Activity API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity#feeds).

That means such an event (switch to private) is likely not visible.
The switch to public should be listed with [`GET /events`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity#list-public-events).

But:

> Only events created within the past 90 days will be included in timelines.
> Events older than 90 days will not be included (